# Display Custom Post type display individually

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I display my custom post type specifically?

Example I have 3 contents of my custom post type. 1 Awesome, 2 Great, 3 Rock

how can I display "1 awesome" in section 1, also "2 Great" display in section 2

Here's my custom post type code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'homeSectionContent',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Home Contents' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Section Content' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array(
       'title',
       'editor',
       'custom-fields',
       'thumbnail',
       'excerpt'
       )
    )
  );
}
```

but my problem is that I can't display them individually.

Here is  my code to display multiple custom post type but I don't have any idea how to display custom post type individually

```
<?php
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'homeSectionContent','post_status' => 'publish','order' => 'ASC');
      $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
      // query_posts($query_string . '&order=ASC');
      while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
        <h1 class="home-header aligncenter"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>  
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: hey! just wanted to check in on you, did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the "posts_per_page" parameter in your query 
example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'homeSectionContent',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
```

this will return only one post. you can get other posts individually as well. simply use the "offset parameter like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'homeSectionContent',
    'offset' => 2,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
```

this will return the 3rd post that would have been in your query.

Let me know if this worked for you, or if i did not fully answer your question!